# Run a for loop n times and combine output into a dataframe

Tags: r

I have the following function(s)

```
fitKList <- list()

for (i in 1:50)
  {fitKList[[i]] <- sample(1:1000, 1)}

betweenss_totss <- list()

for (i in 1:50)
  {betweenss_totss[[i]] <- fitKList[[i]] * .25}
```

I would like to be able to iterate through this 1000 times and combine the results in a single data frame. The final output would contain 50 rows with 1000 columns and each column should have different random generated values.

I tried using, so I could combine the list into a df:

```
MC <- replicate(1000, betweenss_totss, simplify=FALSE)
```

But the output from betweenss_totss is the same in every list. How can I do this so that a new fitKList and betweenss_totss is generated each time. I am trying to approximate a monte carlo simulation so if there are any easier ways to do that, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use

```
do.call( rbind ,betweenss_totss)
```

You are only sampling one thing, so you only get on col.

if you sampled a 1000, you would have a 1000 cols and 50 rows

```
fitKList <- list()

for (i in 1:50)
{fitKList[[i]] <- sample(1:1000, 1000)}

betweenss_totss <- list()

for (i in 1:50)
{betweenss_totss[[i]] <- fitKList[[i]] * .25}

data.frame( do.call( rbind ,betweenss_totss) )
```

Comment: Thanks! Sampling data was just to provide an example for this question. I am trying to apply this to the results of a model that only returns a single value so I cannot sample 1000 times

Comment: @StephenGardner, so does the do.call approach solve your issue?

Comment: no not fully. I am looking for a way to loop through the above functions n times and combine that output into a data frame.

Comment: do.call allows me to create a data frame, but unless I am sampling 1000 with your method (which I cannot do, because the real data is not a sample and only has a single value) only one column is returned

Comment: @StephenGardner, can you use dput, to capture the object